# High to Low logic level converter with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, converter, logic-level, step-down

I'm designing a sniffer circuit to tap input signals from various machines. The type of signal varies from input pulses and UART communication, the voltage varies from 5V to 12V.

These are the requirements of the circuit:

- Shares a common ground with the external machine.
- Does not require tapping the VCC voltage of the external machine.
- High impedance input. (Does not draw any current from the input)
- Inverts input signal.
- Steps down logic levels as high as 12V to 3.3V.

My first proposed solution is to use a 74HC4050 IC. However, this does not invert the signal and pulls the output pins low when the input is open. Additionally, the IC is quite expensive and does not come in a lower channel version.

My second solution is the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgXdM6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will this work? Or are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: _"Additionally, the IC is quite expensive and does not come in a lower channel version."_ What annual volume are you planning on?

Comment: 500 but this could possibly scale up in the future. However, it is not a major concern as of now.

Comment: 0.25080 USD a piece at 500 staffing at Digi-Key at the moment. Probably your best option as all quirks have been ironed out by TI/NXP already, faster and lower power consumption.

Comment: When you say very high input impedance, practically, the input leakage will not be 0A. Is say 5uA ok? Also, what about the input capacitance allowed? What will be the frequency of the signal appearing on the input? Do we have to manage the case where input is open? Could you take a look at 74HC4049 instead which gives an inverted output?

Comment: Consider adding a pulldown to the gate of the MOSFET, if the input isn't guaranteed to do that.

Comment: @sai yes 5uA should be ok, as it is a sniffer circuit, the goal is to minimize the effect on the signal line. The max frequency of the pulses is only 50Hz, but it will be much higher for sniffing UART circuits that operate at a 9600 baud rate. Ideally, it is best if we can manage the case where input is open, to have a default value. I have looked at the 74HC4049 but sourcing that component can be quite challenging. Which leads me to my question, is a simple MOSFET circuit sufficient for this?

Comment: @evildemonic I did at first but I'm concern that the impedance of the circuit will be relatively low and it will be drawing some current.

Comment: It can be a high value resistor so the current will be negligible.  The important thing is to provide a path to discharge the gate capacitance so the MOSFET can turn all the way off reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that 5uA input leakage is ok, a high value of resistor say 2.4MΩ or more can be used from M1 gate to ground. Without this, anyway R3 is limiting the current to 330uA. So, anyway it is ok but, if the output is mid-rail, it could create problems downstream.

You'll be loading the input line with a cap of max 50pF. Given that you are going to use it for low frequency, it should be fine but do check if the circuit you plan to sniff has any restriction on the cap load.

Output rise time will be of the order of 1.5us (assuming 25pF load and 25pF MOSFET output cap). So, period of the input waveform should be atleast 10 times more. If this rise time is not acceptable, you can use a PMOS instead of the resistor (CMOS inverter) but then, you need to check the shoot-through current during the switching (not an issue if input has very sharp edges) and must use a pulldown resistor to define the gate when input is open. If input has very slow edges, there is a risk of chattering at the output in this configuration. To manage this, you need to use a Schmitt trigger instead of this.